# How to drop columns from Spark DataFrame containing only null values using Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to drop columns from `DataFrame` whose all values are null. Suppose I have a DataFrame -

```
 col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
----------------------------           
  1     null    C1    null
  2     null   null   null                 
 null   null   null   null
  3     null    C2    null
```

Column `col2` and `col4` have all `null` values, so I have to drop those columns from DataFrame whose all values are null. So the final DataFrame would look like the following-

```
 col1 | col3  
--------------          
  1      C1    
  2     null                        
 null   null        
  3      C2
```

The operation should take close to O(1).